# Counting divs without using class

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

I am trying to count the number of gives in a group without using the class name:

```
<div class="item" id="home1">home 1 text here</div>
<div class="item" id="home2">home 2 text here</div>
<div class="item" id="home3">home 3 text here</div>
<div class="item" id="home4">home 4 text here</div>
```

I have tried this

```
alert($(['id^="home"']).length);
```

But it keeps giving me 0

Is there a more appropriate way of doing this?

Comment: The more appropriate way would be using the class name. Why are you class averse?

Comment: That class name is used elsewhere in the application for counting a larger group of divs but not all the divs.

Comment: Elements can have multiple classes `<div class="item home" id="home1">home 1 text here</div>`

Comment: You could be more specific in your selector such as defining the specific parent `$('#myparentid div.item')` or even adding a new class to the element `<div class="item specialitem" id="home1"></div>...$('div.specialitem')`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

syntax error, try this:

```
alert($('[id^="home"]').length);
```

Answer (score 1):

If your divs are all siblings in a containing element you could do `$('.parentClass').find('div').length;`

Answer (score 0):

Your single quotes are in the wrong place.  You had them inside the square brackets.  They need to be outside the brackets.

Try this

```
alert($('[id^="home"]').length);
```

**Example:** http://jsfiddle.net/jasongennaro/dVtzx/

Answer (score 0):

you have got the selector wrong

```
alert($("[id^='home']").length);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/zPBv5/

Answer (score 0):

I would wrap the divs in another div, and give the wrapper an id.
Then counting the divs only within this wrapper.

```
<div id="wrapper">
    <div class="item" id="home1">home 1 text here</div>
    <div class="item"id="home2">home 2 text here</div>
    <div class="item" id="home3">home 3 text here</div>
    <div class="item" id="home4">home 4 text here</div>
</div>
```

This also will be more efficient. As it finds `#wrapper` using `getElementById`, and then runs only on it's children, and not on the whole document's elements, searching for the id pattern.

```
 alert($("#wrapper .item").length);
```

Answer (score 0):

Your problem seems to have been solved (misplaced brackets) but there are ways to select elements besides using `id` substrings.

```
<div id="homeDiv">
    <div class="item" id="home1">home 1 text here</div>
    <div class="item" id="home2">home 2 text here</div>
    <div class="item" id="home3">home 3 text here</div>
    <div class="item" id="home4">home 4 text here</div>
</div>
```

JS:

```
$("#homeDiv .item"); //If they are wrapped in a div, specify that and use descendant selection
```

---

```
<div class="item home" id="home1">home 1 text here</div>
<div class="item home" id="home2">home 2 text here</div>
<div class="item home" id="home3">home 3 text here</div>
<div class="item home" id="home4">home 4 text here</div>
```

JS:

```
$("div.item.home"); //Elements can have multiple classes
$(".home");  //And you can use any class name to select them.
```